# NSUnknownKeyException in uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to play a video file (m4v) from resource folder of my app (i.e local video). but I am not able to play the video. I referred apple's sample project for the MPMoviePlayer.

Also when i am giving background color to my movieplayercontroller object its appearing as its behind some black view and the black view ahead is showing that something is loading for few seconds but nothing get loaded and it results in black screen only.

Can someone help me out with it. please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Also, i have taken screenshot of the screen with problem so that you all can understand what i am trying to say but i dont know how to post it here. :(

Comment: If you'd like to share an image just use an image hosting service and post a link, if you'd like us to help with your issue you'd be best off posting the accompanying code as well.

Comment: Thanks for your time Nicholas. I was missing to setmovieSourceType which was causing the problem. I added this and my problem is solved.

Comment: Don't forget you can answer your own question and accept it, it's useful for if anyone comes across this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
NSURL *urlObj = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlString];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1,1));
MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlObj];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[player.view setBounds:self.view.bounds];
// when playing from server source type shoud be MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming
[player.moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming]; // I was missing this line therefore video was not playing
[player.moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];


[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[player.moviePlayer play];
```